# How to change the domain of url that the browser is showing in download page

Tags: php

I have a script which used to download files from my website, On downloading page of browser, it shows the url of sender. Like

If file is downloading from `http://localhost/w/download.zip` it shows the same url, But what I want to give is some fake domain or url, like `http://www.example.com/download.zip`.

Means I want to change the url or domain that the browser is reporting the download is from.
I know it can be done by this also

```
<a href="download.php?d=<?php echo $_GET['d']; ?>" target="_blank">Download!</a>
```

But it does not change the domain. And shows me another link from that my domain.

Question is : ***How do I do that?***

Comment: Are you wanting to change the URL that the browser is reporting the download is from, or the hover URL that the user sees before clicking?

Comment: @stwalkerster  
Yes, I want to change the URL that the browser is reporting the download is from.

Comment: @Adityapandey So You want to change the domain of downloading url, Why don't you try to change .htacess file

Comment: @Kumar Yes, that I want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show a different URL to the user when he hovers the mouse over, you could use JavaScript for it, Google itself does something similar. Here's a simple example:

```
<a href="https://www.google.com/" onclick="location.href='https://www.facebook.com/';return false;">Google?</a>
```

The browser will show google.com when hovering over the link, but when clicked, JavaScript redirects to facebook.com and cancels the default behaviour.

Note that this won't work if JavaScript is disabled in the user's browser (very few cases nonetheless).

Demo: http://output.jsbin.com/pehehorune

Comment: But I will use it for downloading files, will it works? anyway thanks

Comment: Yes! It will work :) Just put your download link instead of the facebook URL